# I cant debug this code

Tags: msp430

```
#include <msp430.h>

#define LED_RED BIT0
#define LED_GREEN BIT6
#define BUTTON BIT3

char Kma = 3;
volatile unsigned int adc_value = 0;
volatile unsigned int adc_flag = 0;

void main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD; // Stop watchdog timer

    P1DIR |= LED_RED | LED_GREEN; // Set LED pins as outputs
    P1OUT &= ~(LED_RED | LED_GREEN); // Turn off LEDs

    P1DIR &= ~BUTTON; // Set button pin as input
    P1REN |= BUTTON; // Enable pull-up resistor on button pin
    P1OUT |= BUTTON; // Set pull-up resistor on button pin

    ADC10CTL0 = ADC10SHT_2 + ADC10ON + ADC10IE; // ADC10 control register 0
    ADC10CTL1 = INCH_10 + ADC10SSEL_0; // Use A10 (P1.4) as input channel, ADC10OSC as ADC10 clock source
    ADC10AE0 |= BIT4; // Enable analog input on P1.4

    // Initializing unused ports (Port 2 and Port 3)
    P2DIR = 0x00; // Set Port 2 as inputs
    P2REN = 0xFF; // Enable pull-up/down resistors for Port 2
    P2OUT = 0xFF; // Set pull-up resistors for Port 2

    P3DIR = 0x00; // Set Port 3 as inputs
    P3REN = 0xFF; // Enable pull-up/down resistors for Port 3
    P3OUT = 0xFF; // Set pull-up resistors for Port 3

    __enable_interrupt(); // Enable interrupts

    long fdmv = 0; // Initialize fdmv to a default value

    while (1) {
        if (adc_flag) {
            adc_flag = 0;

            // Optimized division using bit shift for divide by 1024
            long gdmv = (adc_value * 3300) >> 10; // Equivalent to divide by 1024 (2^10)
            fdmv = ((Kma - 1) * fdmv + gdmv) / Kma; // Local averaging filter

            if (fdmv > 2000) {
                P1OUT |= LED_RED;
                P1OUT &= ~LED_GREEN;
            } else {
                P1OUT &= ~LED_RED;
                P1OUT |= LED_GREEN;
            }
        }
    }
}

#pragma vector=ADC10_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC10_ISR(void) {
    Kma = 5; // Change filter coefficient

    adc_value = ADC10MEM;
    adc_flag = 1;
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits); // Enter Low Power Mode 0
}
```

Comment: Neither can we if you don’t give us a detailed schematic of your setup, what this is supposed to do, what it actually does, and any errors or traces you may have, at the very least.

Comment: Hello Katia and welcome.  You might tell us something about the hardware or what the code is intended to do.  When you say you can't debug it, you imply it does something wrong: what does it do that's wrong?

Comment: So, you have two leds controlled by the value read by some ADC. What occurs? Are both leds off? Are the interrupts triggered?

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a TI MSP430G2553 or similar processor.

If you use the stdint.h (standard integer) file it will be easier for you and others to read the code. Then you can use uint16_t, uint32_t, etc. I believe that a long is 32-bits.

The most obvious problem is here, you must cast the adc_value to 32-bits so the math won't overflow.

```
long gdmv = (adc_value * 3300) >> 10; // Equivalent to divide by 1024 (2^10)
```

should be:

```
long gdmv = ((long)adc_value * 3300) >> 10; // Equivalent to divide by 1024 (2^10)
```

You either need to request ADC conversions, or setup for continuous conversions. Note that if you are sampling at a high rate, low-power mode won't be as helpful, you might as well wait for the conversion and eliminate the interrupt.

```
  ADC10CTL0 |= ENC + ADC10SC;           // Sampling and conversion start
  while ( ADC10CTL1 & ADC10BUSY )       // Wait for conversion to complete
  {}
```

Code Composer Studio has excellent debugging tools. Have you learned how to use them?

If you really want to use interrupts, you need to be careful. If your main code will execute something after an interrupt, you want to enter low-power mode in the main code; and exit low-power mode in the interrupt.

```
    __bis_SR_register( LPM3_bits );     // Enter LPM0
OR
    __bis_SR_register( LPM0_bits + GIE );     // Enter LPM3 and enable interrupts
    
    __bic_SR_register_on_exit( LPM0_bits );        // Exit LPM
```

Code should always include a minimal description of what it does. The TI examples include a minimal schematic to help.

Write code so that when someone looks at it years from now they can understand it. And if you need motivation, realize that the someone may be you.

The various MCU clocks are often important, summarize how each is derived.

Note that these comments were borrowed from my code and I attempted a quick update for your setup, all may not be correct.

```
//******************************************************************************
//  MSP430G2553 Project Name
//
//
//  Description: This program measures a voltage and does something with the LEDs ...
//
//
//  ACLK = VLO, MCLK =  DCO = SMCLK = 1MHz
//
//
//                  MSP430G2x33/G2x53
//                 -----------------
//                |                 |
//                |                 |
//  Input Volt ---|P1.4/A10     P1.0|--- Red LED 
//                |                 |
//                |             P1.6|--- Green LED 
//                |                 |
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the point's made in the answer from Mattman944, the `ADC10_ISR` interrupt routine ends with:

```
    __bis_SR_register(LPM0_bits); // Enter Low Power Mode 0
```

Which means the MSP430 device will enter low-power-mode 0 which disables the `CPU` and `MCLK`. As a result the `while` loop in the `main` function won't execute which attempts to process the ADC result won't run.